# Unicode string in XML

Tags: xml, unicode

In xml unicode are represented as follows:

e.g:

```
\ue349
```

What if I want to write a string consists of two chars with unicodes e343 e312

How can this be represented in XML?

Comment: That's not how Unicode characters are represented in XML. XML uses `&#xE349;` for numeric references. What you showed is used in Java (among others).

Comment: I used to use it in android .. so how I use it now as a string?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

XML does not use `\ue349` notation. [Character references](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#dt-charref), starting with `&#`, may be used, but they are mostly not needed. XML is usually used with UTF-8 character encoding, so that each character can be written as such. (When generating XML in a program, you might well use a notation like `\ue349` if supported by the programming language.)

In Unicode, the numbers E343 and E312 refer to Private Use codepoints, to which no character is assigned by the standard. They may be used by private agreements as desired, but you should not expect any software or any person to understand them, except by such agreements. With this in mind, the code points U+E343 U+E312 (and hence the characters they may denote by some agreement) can be written as `&#xe343;&#xe312;`.

Comment: U+D8E1 is a reserved (unassigned) code point. This means that no character is assigned to it and it must not be used at all; this may change if a future version of the standard assigns a character to it. Font vendors sometimes use reserved code points, but this violates the standard and has unpredictable effects. Ref.: http://www.unicode.org/versions/latest/ch03.pdf#G2212

Comment: U+D8E1 is a surrogate character, a way of encoding Unicode characters outside the Basic Multilingual Plane; a good example of this is the Emoji character U+1F600 GRINNING FACE. Surrogate characters are used in pairs; for example, U+1F600 can be encoded as the UCS-2 characters U+D83D U+DE00.

Answer (score 16):

`<node>&#xE343;&#xE312;</node>`