# XML How do you include an exclamation point ! in an XML text string? escape sequence?

Tags: xml

I've tried many combinations of escape sequences to get an exclamation point into an xml string in Android's resource folder - to no avail.  What xml string would you use for Help! for example?  Thanks...

Comment: you could use `<![CDATA[...]]>` which doesn't parse anything in between?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11592013/unicode-string-in-xml

Answer (score 8):

An XML file should accept a exclaimation point, except possibly immediately after a open angle bracket.

If it really refuses, you should be able to use a numeric entity:  `Help&#x21;` = Help!

Or you can get verebose `<![CDATA[Help!]]>`

Comment: &#x21 works - thanks.  I looked at dozens of Google and StackOverflow responses and no one shows the lower-case "x".  Is there a table of characters v. xml codes you could point me to for reference?  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

U can add some text in attribute

```
nodElement->SetAttribute( "Name", node_tv->Text);
```

**node_tv->Text has special symbols**