# How to pass the "!" to ant property from parameter?

Tags: xml, bash, ant

I have an ant target like this.

```
<target name="test">
<condition property="expression" value="${expression}" else="">
      <isset property="expression"/>
</condition>
    <echo>Expression is ${expression }</echo>
</target>
```

I want to set its property with a string which contains logical operators like

```
&& || ! etc.
ant test –Dexpression="A||!B"
ant test –Dexpression="!abc"
```

But I found it can't accept the exclamation mark "!".

The echo is

```
A||B
abc
```

How can I pass the "!" to ant property from parameter?

Comment: Ant script is xml, so try `&#x21;` as suggested here:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/14468687/2294676

Comment: Hi alex, that doesn't work:(

Comment: Are you using Windows command prompt or some UNIX shell?  Are you invoking from a command prompt using `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` (Windows) or is the `histexpand` option enabled (UNIX)?

Answer (score 0):

You need to put expression in single quotes. This way bash will not interpret it.

```
ant test –Dexpression='A||!B'
ant test –Dexpression='!abc'
```

Comment: Hi Oleg, I did try the single quotes way, but it didn't work for me. BTW, my ant version is 1.7, is it a version related issue?